# Create new project in Angular 14

Tags: angular

How come when I run:

```
ng new angular-tour-of-heroes
```

It's Angular 13 installed? I thought Angular 14 was the newest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update the global angular cli:

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

After you have to run:

```
ng new angular-tour-of-heroes
```

1. https://angular.io/start
2. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0

Comment: Alternatively I'd introduce the `npx` command, since updating the global angular cli could break other projects :)